# Android EditText offset for the text?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-edittext, drawable

I've created a background drawable for my EditText, but the text showed up IN the image border. I fixed this by setting 'scrollX to -12dip, and this seemed to word in Eclipse, in the graphical layout viewer (pic 1). However on the device it still shows up through the image. I've referenced to my background drawable through a xml file if that matters.

[In Eclipse and a screenshot http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9954/nieuwbitmapafbeelding.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9954/nieuwbitmapafbeelding.png)

*yes, i know the second pic is different, but that's just because i focussed on the view, the problem stays even if I unfocus. :'(*

.

EDIT
I now completely remade the image(s), and used draw9patch. The text offset was fixed, however since I used a vertical gradient in my image, I selected all the pixels (minus the actual border) to prevent having one part gradient -> stretched solid color part -> gradient. Now the height of the background drawable always remains very big.

How is this usually done, if there's a gradient in the image? Probably if you create the image small to begin with, you won't get a very smooth gradient.
How do I fix my problem, and how should it be done?

Answer (score 10):

If you use the `android:paddingLeft=""` attribute in your `EditText`, it will move the `TextView` inside it over a specified number of pixels.

Example:

`android:paddingLeft="30dp"` will move your text to the right 30 density-independent pixels.

Answer (score 2):

How have you actually created the background image? If it's the full image then that's not the best way to do this.

You should be creating a 9-patch image to use as the background; http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: He should do that as a general rule, but that's not the reason he's getting the shifted text.  I think it's because his image on the left side is longer than the default `EditText` image, so the border is farther right.  If he pads to adjust, it should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use editText.setPadding(), it may give you the spacing you need for the text to shift over. It might also apply padding to the background resource as well though. But try it out

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, not a solution...

You can use RelativeLayout, and in XML, use some attributes like alignParentBotton or alignParentLeft something like that instead of absolute position coordinators. If you use the absolute coordinators, sometimes, your ui seems different on different  devices.

Comment: I'm already using a relative layout. I just need the text inside the edittext box to be slightly to the right.